# como leer un archivo estructurado con java

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo con la siguiente estructura:

```
a{a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a},b{a,a,a,,a,a,a,a,a,a,a},c[c,c,c,c,c,,,,c,c,c,c]
```

E tratado de hacerlo con expresiones regulares y con split pero nada no lo e podido lograr.
Alguien me puede ayudar con esto.

Comment: Muestra el codigo que has intentado.

Comment: Aparte de mostrar lo que has intentado... ¿puedes explicar a qué te refieres con *leer* un archivo?, es decir, ¿puedes explicar con más claridad qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: estoy tratando de realizar un sistema administrativo, ahora el archivo lo leo bien pero tengo un problema con la secuencia, como ves las secuencia que muestro al leer me los separa, esto lo guardo en un arraylist, cuando trato de mostrar me muestra lo siguiente: a,{,a,a,a,a.... y asi sucesivamente, ahora lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de imprimir el array por cada secuencia me la muestre como esta en el archivo original solo que separadas y cada secuencia sea un elemento dentro del array y no cada palabra un elemento, al momento tengo que cada letra es una posición dentro del array

Answer (score 1):

Con la ayuda de expresiones regulares puedes capturar grupo de datos. Un grupo se define con los parentesis "()" y el matcher capturará lo que se encuentre dentro. Si tenemos parentesis anidados como "(())" el macher los capturará en el orden jerarquico, en algun momento hice algo parecido a lo que necesitas. Yo necesitaba leer conjuntos y sus elementos.

```
        String regex = "([a-z]+)\\{([a-z,]+)\\}";
        String line = "peliculas{flechaverde,batman}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
            for(int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
```

La salida de estas lineas de codigo:
2
peliculas{flechaverde,batman}
peliculas
flechaverde,batman

Al ultimo grupo ya podía aplicar un split(","), creo que captura de grupos puede ser buena estrategia a seguir.